# Set Argument Name as Variable in R API Function Call

Tags: r

I'm working with an R API that has a function with the following syntax:

```
somefun(...)
```

An example call:

```
somefun(foo = list(a = 10, b = 20))
```

Since there are many variables that can be set with this function (not just 'foo') how would one change "foo" to a variable name in the script?  Something like:

```
x = "foo"    ## or x = "bar", etc
somefun(x = list(a = 10, b = 20))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the cleanest. You can use `eval` + `parse`

```
somefun <- function(...) {
    as.list(match.call())[-1]
}

somefun(foo = list(a = 10, b = 20))
#$foo
#list(a = 10, b = 20)

eval(parse(text=paste0("somefun(", x, " = list(a = 10, b = 20))")))
#$foo
#list(a = 10, b = 20)
```